# How to merge three rows of table into two?

Tags: tables

I want to achieve following table layout including lines and borders, all nice and evenly spaced:

```
|---------------------|
|          |          |
|          |----------|
|          |          |
|----------|          |
|          |          |
|          |----------|
|          |          |
|---------------------|
```

Using this I can't manage to get a horizontal line in the first row:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & 1 \\\cline{2-2}
\multirow{2}{*}{B} & 2 \\\cline{2-2}
                   & 3 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post  a *full* compilable  code that shows your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A}  & 1                  \\
                      \cline{2-2}
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{2} \\
\cline{1-1}
\multirow{2}{*}{B}  &                    \\
                      \cline{2-2}
                    & 3                  \\
\hline                   
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's close. What bothers me is that the right column's cells are not of equal height. I'd like to have the left column's cells span exactly 1.5 rows. Is this possible?

Comment: @Torben Basically it is possible, but fragile: Depending on the contents of the cells, the height and width will vary, and as soon as you change something, the distances will change. If the most important thing is the frame, then it is maybe better to do the grid in `tikz` and then fill in the contents into fixed cells.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}                                  \hline
                                & \multirow{2}{*}{1} \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{A}              &                    \\ \cline{2-2} 
                                & \multirow{2}{*}{2} \\ \cline{1-1}
\multirow{2}{*}{B}              &                    \\ \cline{2-2}
                                & \multirow{2}{*}{3} \\
                                &                    \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The alignment of "A" and "B" seems to be a bit off. Probably you wanted smething like `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}                                  \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A}              & \multirow{2}{*}{1} \\ 
                                &                    \\ \cline{2-2} 
                                & \multirow{2}{*}{2} \\ \cline{1-1}
\multirow{3}{*}{B}              &                    \\ \cline{2-2}
                                & \multirow{2}{*}{3} \\
                                &                    \\  \hline
\end{tabular}` instead?